# serverless framework: local kafka as event source

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, localstack

I'm trying to build a local development environment in order to make my local tests.

I need to use kafka as event-source.

I've deployed a self-managed cluster into my local environment using docker.

An issue is running in my mind [according to documentacion, I need to provide authentication](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/kafka#authentication).

Here there's no problem, the issue is which kind of values documentation is required I provide, AWS secrets.

What do those kind of secret, AWS secrets, have to do with my self-managed self-deployed kafka cluster?

How could I provide my kafka cluster as local event source?

I mean, I thought I only need to provide bootstrap servers, consumer group and topic... Something like knative serverless documentation says.

Any ideas about how to connect to my local kafka?